# Comparative statics for system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Consider the following non-linear differential equations with constant $\alpha$:
\begin{equation}
\frac{dq}{dt}=f(q,A,\alpha)\\
\frac{dA}{dt}=g(q,A)
\end{equation}
where $f$ and $g$ are Lipschitz cont. and $\partial f/\partial \alpha>0$ and $g$ is strictly decreasing in $q$ for all $q,A$.

How do I show: For the unique solutions, when $\alpha'> \alpha$ and for any interior $q_0,A_0$ then for all $t>0$:
\begin{equation}
q(t;\alpha', q_0,A_0)>q(t;\alpha, q_0,A_0)\\
A(t;\alpha', q_0,A_0)<q(A;\alpha, q_0,A_0)
\end{equation}

Comment: Do you know anything about $\frac{\partial f}{\partial A}$ and $\frac{\partial g}{\partial A}$?

Answer (score 0):

This does not hold without additional restrictions.

Consider the system
\begin{align}
\dot{x} &= y + \alpha \\
\dot{y} &= -x,
\end{align}
together with the initial condition $x(0)=y(0)=0$. When $\alpha = 0$ the system has unique solution $(x(t),y(t))=(0,0)$.

Next, let's consider the solution for $\alpha = 1$. This system has solution
$$
\big(x(t),y(t)\big) = \big(\sin(t)\;,\;\cos(t)-1 \big),
$$
which does not satisfy the condition $x(t)>0$ for $t>0$.